# Trying to install mysql-server on AWS EC2 Amazon Linux, but getting Problem: conflicting requests

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS, trying to setup MySQL on EC2.
I enter `sudo yum install mysql-server`
and this following error appears, with a lot more lines.
Error:
Problem: conflicting requests

- nothing provides libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
- nothing provides libssl.so.10()(64bit) needed by mysql-community-server-8.0.11-1.el7.x86_64

I enter `sudo yum install mysql-server` to install mysql.

Answer (score 3):

was having the same issue on AWS ec2, Performed the following steps:

1. Become the root.
2. Then  `vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql.repo` and added

```
[mysql57-community]
name=MySQL 5.7 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/7/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
```

3. run `rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022`
4. run `yum install mysql-community-server`
5. Finally, run `systemctl start mysqld` to start the server.

Hopefully, it helps!

Comment: spent two days on this, Thank you!